# Jquery draggable and resizable bug in opera? How do I fix it

Tags: javascript, debugging, opera, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I am a web programer and was busy making div windows that could be dragged or resized using jquery ui. I have tested my website in other browsers with positive results.

Here is the html

```
     <div id="w2">blabalblablaaba</div>
```

Here is the javascript.

```
   $(function() {
$( "#w2" ).draggable();
  });
```

And yes **I have linked the jquery ui stylesheet and javascript sheets**.
Please help that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine with JQuery 1.9.1 + JQuery UI 1.9.2 in Opera 12.17 and Opera 20

HTML:

```
<div id="w2">blabalblablaaba</div>
```

CSS:

```
#w2 {
   border:2px solid red;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   padding: .5em;
   background:yellow
}
#w2:hover {
   cursor:pointer
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#w2" ).draggable();
});
```

test it at http://jsfiddle.net/q8Thy/2/